# Trying to understand partial template specialization with template template parameters

Tags: c++

I came across this is_specialization implementation found in several posts on SO:

```
    //1 default
    template<typename Test, template<typename...> class Ref> 
    struct is_specialization : std::false_type {};

    //2 specialization
    template<template<typename...> class Ref, typename... Args>
    struct is_specialization<Ref<Args...>, Ref>: std::true_type {};
```

I think I understand that, for example:

```
is_specialization<std::tuple<int, float>, std::variant>::value
```

matches against 1.

But can't understand why:

```
is_specialization<std::tuple<int, float>, std::tuple>::value
```

matches against 2.

Maybe it is because I don't very well understand how the template selection process works.

Which is exactly the process that makes the second example match against 2 if, for the first parameter passed to is_specialization, what is expected is a template (template<typename...> class Ref) and not a template instance?

Thank you very much

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization might help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> for the first parameter passed to is_specialization, what is expected is a template (template<typename...> class Ref) and not a template instance?

That is an incorrect assumption.

Consider this additional specialization.

```
//1 default
template<typename Test, template<typename...> class Ref> 
struct is_specialization : std::false_type {};

//2 specialization
template<template<typename...> class Ref, typename... Args>
struct is_specialization<Ref<Args...>, Ref>: std::true_type {}; 
//             Look here ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

//3 additional specialization
struct is_specialization<std::vector<int>, std::vector>: std::true_type {};
//             Look here ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I've intentionally left any template parameters out of this third example to help illustrate something:

**All three** forms of `is_specialization` expect the **same** template parameters.  Specifically,

```
template<typename Test, template<typename...> class Ref>
```

The `Look here` comments show how the specializations are specializing those parameters.

So, your specialization `//2` does not change what template parameters are expected from `is_specialization`.  They are new template parameters used explicitly to help decide whether `//2` qualifies as a match for your `is_specialization<std::tuple<int, float>, std::tuple>`

The compiler will infer that implicitly supplying `<std::tuple, int, float>` to specialization `//2` will allow it to be a valid specialization when defining `is_specialization<std::tuple<int,float>, std::tuple>`